# flex-direction column not responsive

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am facing a problem with `flex-direction: column` on responsive mode. When I write `flex-direction: column`  to `.container` its not wrapping to responsive like `flex-direction: row`, it's going outside of the layout. How to fix that?

```
   <div class="content">
     <div class="container">

       <div class="box">First Name Man</div>
              <div class="box">First Name Man</div>
       <div class="box">First Name Man</div>
       <div class="box">First Name Man</div>

     </div>
   </div>
```

```
.content {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 800px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}


.container {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
   display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

}

.box {
  width:700px;
  margin: 10px;
  color:white;
  min-height: 70px;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);

  justify-content: space-around;
  background-color: indigo;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Comment: Code in codepen      https://codepen.io/albenis-k-rqeli/pen/jOWNxeQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a fixed `width` setting for `.box` (700px). Change that to `width: calc(100% - 20px)` (i.e. full width minus 20px for the margin left and right) in a media query, then it will work as desired.

Comment: thanks so much, and  is any other method with only flexbox to  fit  the box , or not?

Comment: You just shouldn't use a fixed width when you use `flex-direction: column`. Fixed is fixed (and not responsive)...

Comment: because in flex direction row is worked perfectly but in flex direction   column not worked on container div but in content div worked , however thanks so much for this trick